# Why this destroy function throw Segmentation Fault in single linked list

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, segmentation-fault

I am new to Data Structures and C. this code work correctly in creating and inserting a node but when i call destroy function its case a `Segmentation Fault`.It seems to work correctly if i put all the code in the main function instead of other functions.

**what cases this bug is :**

• `destroy`

• `delete` **IF** deleted the head of the Linked List Only

can anyone please explain to me what is wrong with that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *create_node(int value);
unsigned char insert(node *head, int value);
unsigned char delete_node(node *head, node *old_node);
node *search(node *head, int value);
unsigned char destroy(node *head);

int main(void)
{
    node *head = create_node(1);
    insert(head, 3);
    insert(head, 2);

    destroy(head);

    for(node *i = head; i != NULL; i = i -> next)
    {
        printf("%i\n", i -> value);
    }
}

// Will create a node and return it if succeeded else it will return NULL
node *create_node(int value)
{
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));

    // Check if the node created successfully or not
    if (new_node == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    new_node -> value = value;
    new_node -> next = NULL;

    return new_node;
}

// Insert the node to a list at the beginning of it, return 0 if succeed else number NOT 0
unsigned char insert(node *head, int value)
{
    node *new_node = create_node(value);

    // Check if the node created successfully or not
    if (new_node == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Check if the List is exist or not
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        return 2;
    }

    new_node -> next = head -> next;
    head -> next = new_node;

    return 0;
}

// Delete the node, return 0 if succeeded else number NOT 0
unsigned char delete_node(node *head, node *old_node)
{
    // Check if the node is exist or not
    if (old_node == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    node *back = head;

    // If delete the first node ONLY
    if (head == old_node)
    {
        free(old_node);
        old_node = NULL;
        return 0;
    }

    while (back -> next != old_node)
    {
        back = back -> next;
    }

    back -> next = old_node -> next;
    free(old_node);

    return 0;
}

// destroy the whole linked list, returns 0 if destroid successfully else number NOT 0
unsigned char destroy(node *head)
{
    // Check if the List is exist or not
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    node *temp = head;

    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp -> next;
        destroy(temp);
        delete_node(head, temp);

    }

    delete_node(head, head);

    return 0;
}

// return Pointer to node if founded it else return NULL
node *search(node *head, int value)
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        // If founded it return it's pointer
        if (head -> value == value)
        {
            return head;
        }
        else
        {
            head = head -> next;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Quick style point, don't put a space on both sides of a pointer declaration ```node * head```, it looks like you're trying to multiply them.

Comment: Which exact line of code does the seg fault occur on? Running the program in a debugger will immediately give you that info. And once you are in the debugger you can dump more of the state and trace the program execution to help you find the problem.

Comment: Also, there is some code, like `create_node` and `insert`, that are missing. All Stack Overflow questions requesting debugging help requires a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without that you may be leaving out some code that actually causes the problem and also makes it hard for others to run the code to see/debug the problem themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see exactly where the problem is here, but I do observe that your `distroy` *(sic...)* function is unnecessarily complicated.  If your purpose is to destroy the entire list, you don't need to call a `destroy_node` routine.  Just do something like this: *(pseudocode ...)*

```
while (head != NULL) {
   temp = head->next;
   free(head);
   head = temp;
}
```

Your `destroy_node` routine also looks unnecessarily complicated.  There are only two cases to consider:  deleting the `head` node, and deleting a node that is not the head node.  *(pseudocode)*

```
if (node == NULL) return;
if (node == head_node) {
   head_node = head_node->next;
   free(node);
} else {
   temp = head_node;
   while ((temp != NULL) {
     if (temp->next == node) {
        temp->next = temp->next->next;  // link it out of the list
        free(node);
        return;
     } else {
        temp = temp->next;
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is here :

```
while (temp != NULL)
{
   temp = temp -> next;
   delete_node(head, temp);
}
```

your function `delete_node(node *head, node *old_node)` at the end execute:

```
free(old_node); // you free temp !
```

and you dont set `old_node` to `NULL` if your free this memory, your can't loop a second time here (because temp deleted):

```
while (temp != NULL)
{
   temp = temp -> next;
   delete_node(head, temp);
}
```

Comment: By mistake, i used `delete_node` instead of  `destroy` i was planning to use a recursive algorithm. but anyway The bug is still here after fixing the code.

Comment: @OmarAhmed can you update your code (in the post) please to see what you have done as modifications